# Why do I see the *protect* button on closed questions and what is its use case?

Tags: support

When I look at a closed question like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48169/187), I see a *protect* button at the bottom

> [image]

I have never noticed this before and I thought this is a feature only available for moderators. When I hover over the button, it says *disallow answers by anonymous or very low rep users*. Even *I* cannot answer closed questions, so what is the point in forbidding it for other users.

Can someone shed some light in this?

Comment: As for why there is an option to protect a closed question, check out [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222173/do-not-allow-me-protect-closed-questions) from an SE representative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ["Protect Questions"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) privilege is a [pretty old one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/), so I guess you just never noticed it all this while! I don't know why it appears on this closed question, but in general, protecting a question

- prevents answers from "new users" (< 10 rep)
- prevents answers from users on other SE sites who only have an association bonus here (i.e. 101 rep but no participation).

Typically it is used to prevent [drive-by answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7597/5) to popular questions or [spam](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15597/5) on certain "honey pot" questions (because of certain keywords). Incidentally, both those questions were not protected because they appeared to be on-off instances, but we do have a few of them that are. The system automatically protects a question if it has 3 answers by new users that were deleted or if 5 new users post answers in a 24 hour period. In the past, the protection feature was also used pre-emptively when a post hit reddit or hacker news (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11819/5) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11350/5), for example) but this is discouraged now (feel free to unprotect them to test your powers!).

Also read:

- [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765)
- [Changes and guidelines for the Protected Question status](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/)

Comment: Why do I see the protect button on closed questions **only**? Can you protect every question?

Comment: I have to correct myself: I see the protect button on other questions too. I got the wrong impression and I found the answer in the second link you gave: Privileged users can protect and unprotect any question **over a day old**. Thanks for providing the information.

Comment: Regarding "... but this is discouraged now ..." I think I missed that memo, or simply forgot it.  Reference?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164080) are what I was referring to. I didn't immediately remember where I read this, otherwise I would've linked to it in my answer :)